# Roxygen2: "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘testthat’"?

Tags: r, class, r6

This is a follow up from a previous question.

[How to integrate new R6Class functions stored in independent files into an existing R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550457/how-to-integrate-new-r6class-functions-stored-in-independent-files-into-an-exist/37555727#37555727)

In summary, in trying to load a function stored in a file. I managed to do it by altering **manually** the NAMESPACE and Collate in the DESCRIPTION and rebuilding the package. However, I am sure this is not standard practice since the package already has a man folder and .Rd files created with roxygen2. However, when I try to use roxygen2 to manage my NAMESPACE and Collate in the DESCRIPTION, the following error pops up.

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating mypackage documentation
Loading mypackage
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘testthat’
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The working directory contains a folder tests with a testhat.R file and a second folder full of functions.

Any hint of why roxygen2 is falling to produce the documentation and update the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION?

Comment: do you have the `testthat` package installed?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Can you make you comment an answer so I can mark the question as answered? I didn't know testthat was a package...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the `testthat` package

---

[testthat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) is a package that is

> A unit testing system designed to be fun, flexible and easy to set up.

The [test](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html#tests) section of Hadley's [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html) book (online) is a good guide on how to use it.

In fact, I recommend going through the whole book as it will introduce you to some best-practices for creating packages. I've used it a **lot**!